# Why object destructuring isn't work at style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The HTMLelement is an object. The style is an object too. So why this code doesn't work? Without destructuring everything works fine, so it isn't a big problem, i just want to know the reason.

```js
const changeColor = () => {
  const div = document.querySelector("div");
  let {color, background} = div.style;
  color = "red";
  background = "blue";
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  color: blue;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div onClick = "changeColor()">
  <p>Example</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Destructuring doesn't work like that.  You're assigning local variables only.

Comment: It does work, but then you need to do `Object.assign(div.style, { color, background })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
const changeColor = () => {
  const div = document.querySelector("div");
  let {color, background} = div.style;       // ***
  color = "red";
  background = "blue";
};
```

is exactly the same as this other than that `div.style` is evaluated once, not twice:

```
const changeColor = () => {
  const div = document.querySelector("div");
  let color = div.style.color;               // ***
  let background = div.style.background;     // ***
  color = "red";
  background = "blue";
};
```

Changing the local variable doesn't have any effect on the object property in either case. The local variable got the **value** of the object property, it has no enduring link back to it.

Putting it another way: Destructuring just creates locals, it doesn't create an object that's a kind of "view" onto the original object providing accessors to the original object's properties. (That would be kind of interesting, but it's not what destructuring does.)

You could do this, though:

```
const changeColor = () => {
  const {style} = document.querySelector("div");
  style.color = "red";
  style.background = "blue";
};
```

That works because we're grabbing a reference to the div's `style` object and modifying its properties directly.

Or, leaving destructuring behind entirely:

```
const changeColor = () => {
  Object.assign(document.querySelector("div").style, {
      color: "red",
      background: "blue"
  });
};
```

and if the function accepts those as parameters, then:

```
const changeColor = (color, background) => {
  Object.assign(document.querySelector("div").style, {color, background});
};
```

which you'd call via `changeColor("red", "blue");`.

Comment: Could also do `Object.assign(style, { color, background })`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - After setting the locals, yes (`div.style`).

Answer (score 6):

destructuring just creates new local variables which means that

```
let {color, background} = div.style
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
let color = div.style.color
let background = div.style.background
```

and if you then follow those lines with

```
color = "red"
background = "blue"
```

You have not assigned a new object property to anything, you've only assigned new values for local variables.